# How to redirect via TemplateView.as_view to .html file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to create an url which redirects to a simple static .html file using:

```
url(r'^impressum/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='impressum.html'), name='impressum'),
```

As far as I understand the template_name argument takes the location of the .html file. I tried several variations of the above code, trying to redirect to the file but always get a 404 error when loading localhost:8000/impressum/

This is how my [Folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVu3y.png) looks. I tried "lwc/templates/impressum.html" and "templates/impressum.html". What am I doing wrong / how does this path direction work exactly

EDIT: below my TEMPLATE_DIRS settings:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried with `r'^impressum/$'` ?

Comment: The dollar shouldn't make a difference. However, it's a good idea to add it, otherwise the url pattern will work for `/impressum/other-url/` as well as `/impressum/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find my error:

this is how my urls.py looked:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'joins.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<ref_id>.*)$', 'joins.views.share', name='share'),
    url(r'^impressum/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='impressum.html')),
)
```

I put the impressum url on the top and then it worked out. I remembered from a tutorial that there is a certain logic how django checks the urls line by line and if you have an url with an extension you have to put before the url without any in order to make it work

Answer (score 2):

This might help now.

```
Template.as_view()
```

This function looks the default django library folder.
So, add your template directory to your django setting.

I guess you have setting in setting_old.py ( by default setting.py).
Because the function looks **TEMPLATES** directory first,
add your template directory, after the manage.py folder, to the setting like below.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'templates',   # <- here 
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: As a complemment: "Thus, when (for example) the APP_DIRS option of a DjangoTemplates backend is set to True in TEMPLATES, a template location could be: /path/to/project/books/templates/books/publisher_list.html" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/